# Automatically add preformatted header in document with dynamic fields

Tags: google-docs

I have a Google Docs file that gets updated every week. Every week I need to add a new Heading 2 header with this format:

Notes meeting - #current_date# - Project #number# - #note_taker#

Is there any way to say: Insert new header that automatically creates a new header in the right format with the current date? That's my main question.

Comment: Welcome @Jimmy, please edit the question to limit it to one  specific problem.

Comment: I've updated the question